# Google Calendar - iCalendar not respecting transparency value

Tags: typescript, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to set the Busy status of an event in Google Calendar to free. Reading through various online resources I found that I need to set the TRANSP to TRANSPARENT however that isn't making any difference.

[image: Calendar showing Busy]

Here is a example of the VEVENT that I am generating.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:693ed103008c78734523f8257e47d9d35b8c50fca0e9473c12b81605a490c4a4
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20230514T133757Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20181001
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20181001
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-MSNCALENDAR-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
SUMMARY:Autumn Term Week 2
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
DESCRIPTION:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
END:VEVENT
```

The source code is here on my [GitHub](https://github.com/chriscn/uoy-week-calendar). I'm struggling to find any specific Google calendar docs. Finding the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) which refer to setting the transparency value as I have done.

I am using a 3rd party library [ical-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical-generator); but that shouldn't be causing the issue because the value is being set to transparent.

After further testing, the event only appears as Busy when I import it through a URL - when I import the ics file; it appears as transparent.

Comment: Since it seems like the results are not consistent I believe it might be a good idea to try [contacting Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) as I suspect having different results by using either link or file should not be expected, alternatively you can try [reporting a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906) as I was unable to find this already reported.